# Error using std::cout in visual cpp console application

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am using visual studio 2013 to build a C++ console application.This is my code which gives an error. I need to write to the console for every function in my application.

```
// RAT.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Process started";
    return 0;
}
```

It gives the following error,

> Error:namespace "std" has no member "cout"

I dont understand why this basic "cout" gives a such error :(
Please help me I am totally confused....

Comment: Note that C is not C++. They are two different languages.

Comment: Any good [beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) or tutorial would tell you what header file is needed.

Comment: You forgot to include iostream

Comment: I did that too but it did not work. But after I restart visual studio it worked. Thank you all :)

Comment: Did you make sure to put that after `#include "stdafx.h"` Remember `#include "stdafx.h"` must come before all other includes or any code.

Comment: Well that could be my problem befor. I connot remember whether I put it above or below #include "stdafx.h" . Thanks that is new knowledge :) And please do not downvote. I really had the problem :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to place `#include <iostream>` as your  header.

Comment: I did that too but it did not work. But after I restart visual studio it worked. Thank you all :)

Comment: _@Djerdjer_ Your answer is neither correct (should be `#include`), nor even complete (you missed to explain it should be `std::cout`).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, he is already including "stdafx.h", so I guess he knows how to include headers using #, but you are right I should have put # (because the sample might be generated automatically from visual studio template). In regard to std::cout, he is already using it.